# Python, splitting a list, map function

Tags: python, list, split

```
people = ['Dr1. Ahmud Agbar', 'Dr2. Kervy Coling-Toag', 'Dr3. Vg Ving Vyasdkrma', 'Dr4. DAld Romead']

def split_title_and_name(person):
    title = person.split()[0]
    LastName = person.split()[-1]
    return '{} {}'.format(title, LastName)

#not-works
k = split_title_and_name(people)
print(k)
print('')

#works
c = list(map(split_title_and_name, people))
print(c)
```

Above is a code, which is part of the lesson, which is part of the online class

I made the working code by myself, my way, which works, however here Author want us to use 'map' function. Definition and object 'c is his creation. With his code, i realized when running object 'k' we get the error as

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.4.objects.py", line 52, in <module>
    k = split_title_and_name(people)
  File "1.4.objects.py", line 48, in split_title_and_name
    title = person.split()[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

why is that, that 'c' works but 'k' not,
why i can split the list using c, but i cannot split the list using k.

Thank You

Comment: `split_title_and_name` expects a string. `people` is a list.

Comment: In the future, I recommend going over your textbook, asking your teacher, discussing with classmates, and Googling documentation before asking a question here. This could've been resolved very quickly with independent research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `split_title_and_name` takes a string as an argument,
so when you pass in a list, you get an error.

Python [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function,

> Returns an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, 
>   yielding the results.

So it applies `split_title_and_name` function to every element of `people` list, which is a string.
That's why it works with `map`.

Comment: Cool, sounds legit, thans, +1!

Comment: Great. If you feel this is helpful, please accept it as the answer.